# Powershell - add 1 to a string

Tags: excel, powershell

The following code:

```
$search.address().tostring()
```

currently outputs cell locations in the format:

```
$B$5
```

but I want to add 1 to it so it becomes

```
$B$6
```

So far I've tried

```
$search.address().tostring()+1
```

But this outputs

```
$B$51
```

How can I get it to add to the any numerical value that appears after the second **$**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this with a regular expression:

```
C:\PS> [regex]::replace('$B$6', '(\$\w+\$)(\d+)', {param($m) $m.groups[1].value + (1 + $m.groups[2].value)})
$B$7
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$search() = $search.row + 1 
$search.address().tostring()
```